# Как обработать изменения SharedPreferences происходящие в другой Activity?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть эквалайзер. Сервис воспроизводит трек и грузит параметры эквалайзера из SharedPreferences. Настройка самого эквалайзера в другой activity. Как сделать так чтобы когда, я изменяю настройку в одной activity, параметры переопределялись в другой? Насколько я понял `onSharedPreferencesChangeListener` работает только если изменения происходят из activity в которой он прописан.

```
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if (key=="lowBand"){
                eqProperties[0]=(short)sharedPreferences.getInt("lowBand",0);
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short)0,eqProperties[0]);
            }else if (key=="lowmiddleBand"){
                eqProperties[1]=(short)sharedPreferences.getInt("lowmiddleBand",0);
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short)1,eqProperties[1]);
            }else if (key=="middleBand"){
                eqProperties[2]=(short)sharedPreferences.getInt("middleBand",0);
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short)2,eqProperties[2]);
            }else if (key=="middlehighBand"){
                eqProperties[3]= (short) sharedPreferences.getInt("middlehighBand",0);
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short)3,eqProperties[3]);
            }else if (key=="highBand"){
                eqProperties[4]= (short) sharedPreferences.getInt("highBand",0);
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short)4,eqProperties[4]);
            }
            eqChange=true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Покажите как вы подписчик создаёте и регистрируете.

Comment: А `sharedPreferences` как создаёте?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать как в [руководстве](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#Listening). Там упомянуто, что анонимный слушатель, не записанный в поле класса может быть удалён GC, спустя какое-то время и, соответственно перестать работать.

Comment: А вообще не проще ли по возвращению из эквалайзера перечитать параметры, вместо слежения за преференсами?

Comment: Строки сравниваются через [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832)

Comment: Зачем их как-то обрабатывать? Нужно просто без этого нагромождения ифов считать, присвоить и пользоваться. В принципе, именно это вы сейчас и делаете, только как-то через совсем другое место.